# How To: Create a 1 column form on sheet2 that will extract data from sheet1

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have tried a number of different values and sorts and filters but my data is difficult to re-align so I think it would be better to use my Sheet_raw as a dB of information, then extract the info from it into a specific format. That's my objective, the extracted data will be uploaded to a dB so I need it in a specific format.

I have two sheets (Sheet Raw & Sheet Upload)

Sheet Raw is raw data that has 5 columns (Title, Type, Title2, SN, ID)

I would like on "Sheet Upload" is type only in Column A an ID# that is from Sheet Raw and it extract the information associated with that specific ID# and put it in column C,D,E,F on "sheet upload"...

So my exercise would be, copy the ID from Sheet Raw, place the ID# in Column A of Sheet Upload, with the formula in-place it would extract the associated data from from Sheet Raw and put it on Sheet Upload columns, C,D,E,F...

Comment: no need for VBA, see `vLookup`

Answer (score 0):

1. go to sheet upload
2. in the same row as ID#, type =vlookup([column where ID],
3. click on the sheet
4. highlight the entire data set
5. continue typing that formula in the other sheet =vlookup([column where ID],[you will have a range here that you selected], FALSE, [type a number corresponding to the column number AFTER ID on the sheet RAW that you want to return])
6. press enter
7. repeat steps for the rest of the columns

more info here:

[vlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)